# Adding nodes OPC UA server

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I'm trying to make OPC UA server.
There is OPC UA Foundation open source that can use server & client.
[OPC UA open source link](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/master)

However, the source has limited data that opc foundation upload on their library by website link.
[Link about node data.](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset/blob/latest/Schema/Opc.Ua.Types.xsd)

So i'm trying to add my own sample data like "test data" or "hello world" ... etc.
I'm looking for any other examples that can add nodes but can't find even one.

Anyone knows about it??
This is the part of server initialization from OPC UA open source.

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Copyright (c) 2005-2020 The OPC Foundation, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * OPC Foundation MIT License 1.00
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use,
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following
 * conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
 * included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY,
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 * The complete license agreement can be found here:
 * http://opcfoundation.org/License/MIT/1.00/
 * ======================================================================*/

using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Opc.Ua;
using Opc.Ua.Configuration;
using Opc.Ua.Server.Controls;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Serilog;

namespace Quickstarts.ReferenceServer
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // Initialize the user interface.
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            ApplicationInstance.MessageDlg = new ApplicationMessageDlg();
            ApplicationInstance application = new ApplicationInstance();
            application.ApplicationType   = ApplicationType.Server;
            application.ConfigSectionName = "Quickstarts.ReferenceServer";

            try
            {
                // load the application configuration.
                ApplicationConfiguration config = application.LoadApplicationConfiguration(false).Result;

                LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration();
#if DEBUG
                loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Debug(restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning);
#endif
                SerilogTraceLogger.Create(loggerConfiguration, config);

                // check the application certificate.
                bool certOk = application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 0).Result;
                if (!certOk)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Application instance certificate invalid!");
                }

                // Create server, add additional node managers
                var server = new ReferenceServer();
                Quickstarts.Servers.Utils.AddDefaultNodeManagers(server);

                // ------------- add nodes here?-----------------------

                // start the server.
                application.Start(server).Wait();

                // check whether the invalid certificates dialog should be displayed.
                bool showCertificateValidationDialog = false;
                ReferenceServerConfiguration refServerconfiguration = application.ApplicationConfiguration.ParseExtension<ReferenceServerConfiguration>();

                if (refServerconfiguration != null)
                {
                    showCertificateValidationDialog = refServerconfiguration.ShowCertificateValidationDialog;
                }

                // run the application interactively.
                Application.Run(new ServerForm(application, showCertificateValidationDialog));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionDlg.Show(application.ApplicationName, e);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <b>ReferenceServer</b> namespace contains classes which implement a Quickstart Server.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exclude/>
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    public class NamespaceDoc
    {
    }
}
```

I want to add my data to nodes.
Thank you.

I tried to use functions about adding nodes in the Opc.Ua library but all failed.
I wonder how to add nodes in OPC UA server.

Should i do in client?
I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples available here: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard-Samples

There is also a class *StandardServer* available, you can start e.g. from inheriting from it and adding your own node managers.